# maven build failure in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to build a simple webapp in eclipse, but getting following errors

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:jar:RELEASE
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:jar:1.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:jar:1.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/1.0/maven-archetype-webapp-1.0.jar. Error code 403, Forbidden: body content-type denied
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:jar:1.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:jar:1.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/1.0/maven-archetype-webapp-1.0.jar. Error code 403, Forbidden: body content-type denied
```

Comment: try cleaning it, and then rebuilding it..

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below steps in Eclipse. It should help you.

```
1. Open Window > Preferences
2. Open Maven > Archetypes
3. Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:
    a) Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
    b) Description: maven catalog
```

Comment: Please verify, in Eclipse, Windows-Preference-Maven-UserSettings, please check the User settings file (settings.xml) exists and the proxy setting inside that file is correctly pointed to your proxy server.